# Http request how to return a list of objects

Tags: c#, api, http

So I have moved from working with Java to C# and man is Spring boot different from C#. I am trying to return a list of objects to a rest API using mongodb database. But the result does not return a list, but rather some object containing my list.

Brand class

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Brand
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet("getAllBrands")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var brands = await _brandRepository.getAllBrands();

    List<Brand> list = (List<Brand>) brands;

    return new JsonResult(list);
}
```

Brand Repository

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Brand>> getAllBrands()
{
    var brands = await _brands.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();
    return brands;
}
```

What I expect

```
[
      {
        "_id": "60d235f60f8c98376ba5b67d",
        "name": "Some brand 1"
      },
      {
        "_id": "60d24d6b0f8c98376ba5b68c",
        "name": "Some brand 2"
      },
      {
        "$id": "6",
        "_id": "60d24e4b0f8c98376ba5b68d",
        "name": "Some brand 3"
      }
    ]
```

What I'm actually getting

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "$values": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "_id": "60d235f60f8c98376ba5b67d",
      "name": "Some brand 1"
    },
    {
      "$id": "4",
      "_id": "60d24d6b0f8c98376ba5b68c",
      "name": "Some brand 2"
    },
    {
      "$id": "6",
      "_id": "60d24e4b0f8c98376ba5b68d",
      "name": "Some brand 1"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I just return a simple list of objects as my result and not that? Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the `Brand` class?

Comment: included the class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JSON you're seeing is expected when your JSON serializer is setup to preserve references. With this, metadata members (`$id`, `$ref`, `$values`) are added so that objects can be referenced within the JSON, instead of duplicated.

More specifically (see [`ReferenceHandler.Preserve`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.referencehandler.preserve?view=net-5.0#remarks)):

> For enumerable types, such as List, the JSON array must be nested within a JSON object containing an $id and $values metadata property, in that order

This is likely configured in your app startup, for example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => 
           options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve);
}
```

To get your expected JSON, you'll need to disable this functionality. You can do this either in the app startup, as before:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => 
           options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = null);
}
```

Or only for that specific endpoint:

```
[HttpGet("getAllBrands")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var brands = await _brandRepository.getAllBrands();

    List<Brand> list = (List<Brand>) brands;

    return new JsonResult(list, new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        ReferenceHandler = null,
        WriteIndented = true
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller try this piece of code

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Brand>> Get()
{
    var brands = await _brandRepository.getAllBrands();

    List<Brand> list = (List<Brand>) brands;

    return Ok(list);
}
```

If `Ok()` have an error just make sure that your `Controller` is inherited from `BaseController`

Comment: Still same result